# How to insert data into database using android studio?

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio

I'm trying to insert data into a database on android studio, the code runs through with no errors, however, the data doesn't get added into the database table.
The data I need to pass through is the title of a movie, Avengers and a showtime 10:00

here is my database helper class

```
package com.missouristate.bryson.finalp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DABASE_NAME = "Movies.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "movies_table";
public static final String ID = "_ID";
public static final String NAME = "Movie_Name";
public static final String SHOWTIME = "Showtime";


public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + ID;
    sqlCreate += " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAME;
    sqlCreate += "text, " + SHOWTIME + " text, )";
             db.execSQL(sqlCreate);


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME );
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean addMovie( String name, String showtime) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("MOVIE", name);
    contentValues.put("SHOWTIME", showtime);
    long result = getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
}
```

here is my showtime class

```
package com.missouristate.bryson.finalp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class showtimes extends Activity {
DatabaseHelper myDB;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.showtimesview);
myDB= new DatabaseHelper(this);

myDB.addMovie(" Avengers", " 1000");
}

}
```

Any help/advice will be appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE FOR LOG-- CHANGED THE addMovie method to

```
    public void addMovie( String name, String showtime) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("MOVIE", name);
        contentValues.put("SHOWTIME", showtime);
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("insert", "Error while trying to add post to database");
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

The log is still showing the data isn't being added into the database

Comment: Have you check value for result flag after insertion? And use try catch block for database related operations so that in case you get any Exception it will get cought

Comment: I added a try catch and a log, the log shows that the data is not being added into the database. I'm not sure if i'm missing something.

Comment: Try printing, e.getMessage() in your catch block, it will give you brief message with exception code which will help you for further investigation

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.

First you have :-

```
String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + ID;
    sqlCreate += " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAME;
    sqlCreate += "text, " + SHOWTIME + " text, )";
```

There is a comma at the end, so a syntax error will arise when the table is created.

Second you have omitted the space between NAME and text, thus the column name will be Movie_Nametext not Movie_Name.

You should instead have :-

```
String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + ID;
    sqlCreate += " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAME;
    sqlCreate += " text, " + SHOWTIME + " text /*<<<<< spurious comma removed */ )";
```

- The comment can be removed.

If the unfixed version above has been run then the database itself will have been created and thus the onCreate method will not run and you would get a table not found error. You should delete the App's data or uninstall the App to delete the database, fix the errors and then rerun the App.

Third you have :-

```
contentValues.put("MOVIE", name);`
```

This will be converted into saying to insert the value held in the variable name into the column called "MOVIE".

According to the table definition there is no such column called MOVIE.

I beleieve that you need to use

```
contentValues.put("Movie_Name", name);
```

or better still

```
contentValues.put(NAME, name);
```

and likewise for all column and table names.

After making the changes and deleting the database and rerunning using the following to test :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDB= new DatabaseHelper(this);
        myDB.addMovie(" Avengers", " 1000");
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(
            myDB.getWritableDatabase().query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null)
        );
    }
}
```

The log contains :-

> ```
> 2019-12-05 19:01:21.441 13419-13419/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44be644
> 2019-12-05 19:01:21.442 13419-13419/? I/System.out: 0 {
> 2019-12-05 19:01:21.442 13419-13419/? I/System.out:    _ID=1
> 2019-12-05 19:01:21.442 13419-13419/? I/System.out:    Movie_Name= Avengers
> 2019-12-05 19:01:21.442 13419-13419/? I/System.out:    Showtime= 1000
> 2019-12-05 19:01:21.442 13419-13419/? I/System.out: }
> 2019-12-05 19:01:21.442 13419-13419/? I/System.out: <<<<<
> ```

Comment: so I did what you stated, the table is created and I do received the log as expected, however the data isn't added into the table. I'm using the SQL console w/in android studio to check

Comment: @ChristianHernandez then it's more than likely *I'm using the SQL console w/in android studio to check* that is misleading you.